# Remove rows in the manage post/page view

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, admin, wp-admin

I'm looking for a way to remove the rows with the title, date and other stuff that's shown on the manage posts/pages screen (highlighted with red in the image below).

I know that I could easily hide it with css, but I'm wondering if it's possible to do it without css and hacking core files.

[image: Visual description on what I want to remove]

Comment: @INT Just a little heads up, I've removed the title column before (using the hooks posted by Rezen), and found it to be more trouble than it was worth, because I also lost the row actions (links that show up when hovering over an item) and also (more obviously) the link to edit the item. So, if you remove the title, you'll need to create a new way to handle that stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm gonna post the CSS anyway because this is the best way to hide it.

```
table.pages thead, table.pages tfoot { display:none; }
```

I didn't find any useful hooks in the source that would allow to pull the actual HTML for the table header and footer out.

Comment: Oh, that's unfortunate. I'll mark this as the accepted answer for now. Hopefully there will be a hook in the future.